# ElasticSearch filter on aggregations without affecting aggregation counts

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

We're using ElasticSearch to find offers based on 5 fields, such like some 'free text', offer state and client name. We also need to aggregate on the two fields client name and offer state. So when someone enters some free text and we found say 10 docs with state closed and 8 with state open, the 'state filter' should contain closed(10) and open(8).

Now the problem is, when I select the state 'closed' to be included in the filter, the aggregation result for open changes to 0. I want this to remain 8. So how can I prevent the filter on the aggregations to influence the aggregation itself?

Here is the first query, searching for 'java':

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
            ],
            "must": {
                "simple_query_string": {
                    "query" : "java"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "OFFER_STATE_F": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 0,
                "field": "offer_state_f",
                "min_doc_count": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1,
    "fields": ["offer_id_ft", "offer_state_f"]
}
```

The result is this:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 960,
    "max_score": 0.89408284000000005,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_type": "offer",
        "_index": "select",
        "_id": "40542",
        "fields": {
          "offer_id_ft": [
            "40542"
          ],
          "offer_state_f": [
            "REJECTED"
          ]
        },
        "_score": 0.89408284000000005
      }
    ]
  },
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "timed_out": false,
  "aggregations": {
    "OFFER_STATE_F": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "REJECTED",
          "doc_count": 778
        },
        {
          "key": "ACCEPTED",
          "doc_count": 130
        },
        {
          "key": "CANCELED",
          "doc_count": 22
        },
        {
          "key": "WITHDRAWN",
          "doc_count": 13
        },
        {
          "key": "LONGLIST",
          "doc_count": 12
        },
        {
          "key": "SHORTLIST",
          "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
          "key": "INTAKE",
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      ],
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0
    }
  },
  "took": 2
}
```

As you see, the sum of the client_state_f buckets is equal to the total hits (960). Now, I include one of the states in the query, say 'ACCEPTED'. So my query becomes:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "offer_state_f": "ACCEPTED"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }            
            ],
            "must": {
                "simple_query_string": {
                    "query" : "java"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "OFFER_STATE_F": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 0,
                "field": "offer_state_f",
                "min_doc_count": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1,
    "fields": ["offer_id_ft", "offer_state_f"]
}
```

What I want is 130 results, but the client_state_f buckets stilling summing up to 960. But what I got is this:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 130,
    "max_score": 0.89408284000000005,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_type": "offer",
        "_index": "select",
        "_id": "16884",
        "fields": {
          "offer_id_ft": [
            "16884"
          ],
          "offer_state_f": [
            "ACCEPTED"
          ]
        },
        "_score": 0.89408284000000005
      }
    ]
  },
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "timed_out": false,
  "aggregations": {
    "OFFER_STATE_F": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "ACCEPTED",
          "doc_count": 130
        },
        {
          "key": "CANCELED",
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "INTAKE",
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "LONGLIST",
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "REJECTED",
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "SHORTLIST",
          "doc_count": 0
        },
        {
          "key": "WITHDRAWN",
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      ],
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0
    }
  },
  "took": 10
}
```

As you can see, only the ACCEPTED bucket is filled, all the others are 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer with the help of a colleague, and the thing is, Val i is right. +1 for him. What I did was placing ALL of my query filters in the post_filter, and that's the problem. I only have to place the filters for the fields on which I want to agregate in the post_filter. Thus:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
            {
                "term": {
                    "broker_f": "false"
                }
            }
            ],
            "must": {
                "simple_query_string": {
                    "query" : "java"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "OFFER_STATE_F": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 0,
                "field": "offer_state_f",
                "min_doc_count": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "post_filter" : {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "offer_state_f": "SHORTLIST"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1,
    "fields": ["offer_id_ft", "offer_state_f"]
}
```

And now the result is correct:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 5,
    "max_score": 0.76667790000000002,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_type": "offer",
        "_index": "select",
        "_id": "24454",
        "fields": {
          "offer_id_ft": [
            "24454"
          ],
          "offer_state_f": [
            "SHORTLIST"
          ]
        },
        "_score": 0.76667790000000002
      }
    ]
  },
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "timed_out": false,
  "aggregations": {
    "OFFER_STATE_F": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "REJECTED",
          "doc_count": 777
        },
        {
          "key": "ACCEPTED",
          "doc_count": 52
        },
        {
          "key": "CANCELED",
          "doc_count": 22
        },
        {
          "key": "LONGLIST",
          "doc_count": 12
        },
        {
          "key": "WITHDRAWN",
          "doc_count": 12
        },
        {
          "key": "SHORTLIST",
          "doc_count": 5
        },
        {
          "key": "INTAKE",
          "doc_count": 0
        }
      ],
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0
    }
  },
  "took": 4
}
```

Comment: Don't forget +1 "for him" ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You need to move your filters into the [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-request-post-filter.html) section instead of the `query` section.

That way, the filtering will applied after the aggregations are computed and you'll be able to aggregate the whole set of data, but only get result hits matching your filters.

Comment: Hi, this does not achieve the desired result. I want to search on 'free text', count the occurances per state / client name WITHIN the results and then use those states / names as a multi select filter in narrowing the result. But the multiselect should be an 'OR'-wise filter. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood the problem. Let me think about it, unless someone comes with a good solution in the meantime. maybe if you could share what you already have now, it would probably help picture it.